# Cannot access data passed through delegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am trying to understand delegate and I don't get why it says that I have used unresolved identifier 'data'.

```
//This is my sendingVC

import UIKit

protocol TextFieldDelegate {
func userEnteredText(text: String)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

var delegate: TextFieldDelegate? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


@IBAction func sendButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if delegate != nil {
        if textField.text != nil {
            let data = textField.text
            delegate?.userEnteredText(text: data!)
        }
    }
}

}
```

The problem is with this code below for my receivingVC I am not able to accesss data variable which should be passed by the delegate.

```
//This is my receivingVC
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, TextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func userEnteredText(text: String) {
    label.text = data // Use of unresolved identifier 'data'
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "sendSegue" {
        let destVC: ViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
        destVC.delegate = self
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Because you've said that the input to that function will be called `text`, not `data`.  `data` is its name in a different function.

Comment: That fixed my problem. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code:

```
func userEnteredText(text: String) {
    label.text = text
}
```